# Userdefaults from old swift app to new ionic app

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, userdefaults

I've maintained an iOS app developed in swift for few months but now I'm ready to change it with a newly developed app in ionic. I'm facing a problem with reading userdefaults in the new app.
In the old app I used this piece of code to store in userdefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("ciao", forKey: "prova")
```

And in the new app I use capacitor storage plugin to try to retrieve the old properties with this piece of code:

```
const prop = await Storage.get({ key: 'prova' });
this.retrievedProp = prop.value;
```

But the returned value is null

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you expecting the value not to be null? Is this 'new app' is a different app from the 'old app'?

Comment: It's different in language, but with the same bundle id, so the old one is overwritten by the new one